# How to execute a method only after completion of another in java

Tags: java, swt

I have the following code inside a SWT Button SelectionListener :

```
loadChildren(parent);
tableViewer.refresh();
```

I dont want the tableViewer to be refreshed until the loadChildren(parent) is executed.

How do i achieve this?

Comment: What makes you think it would? Does loadChildren start a new thread?

Comment: Does `loadChildren()` run on a separate thread? Does it execute any async methods? If not, then they are executed one after the other.

Comment: Just call it from the loadChildren method.

Comment: @Baz I'm not sure if loadChildren() runs on a seperate thread. It is an existing(not my own) method in the system whose code is not exposed. Sometimes even before it is run the TableViewer is getting refreshed and hence not loading correct results.

Answer (score -1):

Because of the lack of your response I can only give you this answer.
Call the refresh method in the loadChildren method.